# Query on PA to get all person accounts which do not have an OCR associated to it

Tags: soql, person-accounts

I am trying to get a list of all PA which do not have an Opportunity associated with it. Our PA and Opportunities are associated via ocr but PA does not have a direct relation with OCR. For example, I have 10 PA, out of which only 6 of them have OCR, I am trying to write a query which will give me a list of the other 4 person accounts, can someone give me an idea on the query, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should give you what you want:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE IsPersonAccount = true
AND PersonContactId NOT IN (SELECT ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole)
```

Comment: that was simple! thank you so much